# Alias for app URI in Django project urls.py

Tags: django, django-urls, django-apps

My Django project "animals" has an app called "birds".  In animals/urls.py the "birds" URIs are routed to birds/urls.py like this:

```
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^birds/', include('birds.urls')),
    url(r'^b/',     include('birds.urls')), # alias
]
```

The "birds/" is the official, permanent base URI; "b/" is accepted as a shortcut/alias.

How can I have the "b/" URIs (permanently) redirected to "birds/", such that even though users can enter "b/penguin", the address bar of the browser will (ultimately) show "birds/penguin"?  I prefer not to touch any code in the "birds" app, because it should not know (care) how the project maps URIs to the app.

I have tried to use

```
RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='birds'))
```

but this results in a 410 Gone response.  And

```
RedirectView.as_view(url='/birds/'))
```

redirects /b/penguin to /birds/, killing my bird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try something like that:

```
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^birds/', include('birds.urls')),
    url(r'^b/(?P<path>.*)$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/birds/%(path)s')),
]
```

Comment: This works for me (Django version 1.9.5). My browser logs that the initial `/b/penguin` request gets a `302 Found` status response from Django accompanied by a `/birds/penguin` Location header.  The browser then makes a second `/birds/penguin` request that is `200 OK`.
I have added the `permanent=True` attribute to make Django return `301 Moved Permanently` instead of `302 Found`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware) to handle the redirects for you

```
class BirdMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin, object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if '/b/' in request.path:
             return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path.replace('/b/', '/birds/'))
        return None
```

The implementation may need a bit of work but the actual method stands, check the current path and if the `/b/` is present, redirect it to your required destination.

Otherwise, you could specify a redirect view by iterating over every url in `birds` but this would get messy for urls in birds that are a namespace to other urls.

Comment: P.S: Save the birds!

Comment: I think, the birds are now safe. This approach seems very appropiate and clean.

Comment: DRY violation - your middleware assumes _way_ too much about the url mapping, and will break as soon as anyone change the urlpatterns, adds i18n urls etc.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - Agreed, the given implementation was only for demonstration purposes and there are ways to extract the hard coded strings (Admittedly, I prefer the other answer)

Comment: @Sayse the "other answer" suffers from a similar problem.